# Applying Radon-Nikodym and Riesz Representation Theorem to Prove a Proposition

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, radon-nikodym, riesz-representation-theorem

I have a paper that I am working on. I wanted to know can a function $\nu$ which is absolutely continuous with respect to measure $\mu$ be represented as an integral where the function is having a factor multiplied in the variable.

From the theory of vector measures, it is clear that, if $(I,\mathscr{F}, \lambda)$ is a finite measure space then Riesz Representation Theorem and Radon-Nikodym Theorem guarantee that there exists a non-negative real-valued  measurable function $f$ on $I$ such that for $E \in \mathscr{F}$ we can find
\begin{equation*}
     \nu (E) = \int_{E}f d\lambda
 \end{equation*}

For example, the function $f$ is having two variables $\{\alpha_1, \alpha_2\}$ and for each variable, there is a factor multiplied which is again a vector $\{r_1,r_2\}$. So, the value would be
\begin{equation*}
     \nu (E) = \int_{E}f (r_1\alpha_1,r_2\alpha_2) d\lambda
 \end{equation*}

Can someone explain?

Comment: Change of variables?

Comment: It is actually the multiplication of variables where I want to say that $r_1 \times \alpha_1$ will also satisfy the property. You can say that its a modification of variables.